# IIS Rewrite URL to remove duplicate query strings

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Is it possible to rewrite/redirect a url such as this:

```
http://example.com?id=123&id=123
```

To instead be:

```
http://example.com?id=123
```

The actual reason for doing this is a bug in code, but a URL rewrite/redirect would be a quick workaround.

Comment: @downvoter: Not really a broad question as it relates directly with the IIS URL Rewrite module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't realize it was possible to add a condition for `{QUERY_STRING}` that matches the pattern `id=(.*)&id=.*` and then just redirect to `http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}?id={C:1}`